# Border.Effect binding leak memory but Border.Background does not

Tags: c#, wpf

Using updated .NET 4.0, I found a strange memory leak that can be reproduced by following sample code.

- app.xml has some application wide resources that bind to properties in app.xml.cs. The resource that create leak is a `<DropShadowEffect>` whose `Color` dependency property is bound to a property in App object.
- The main window has a button to launch a LeakWindow in which resources defined in app.xml are used.
- When the leak window is closed, it's not garbage collected. **This
  only happen if the leak window use above mentioned `DropShadowEffect` resource. Does not happen on a `SolidColorBrush` whose `Color` is also bound to the same source.**

Really appreciate if someone can tell me why this leak happens on the `DropShadowEffect` but not on the `SolidColorBrush`?

**App.xml**

```
<Application x:Class="WpfSimple.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <!--this one make GC unable to collect LeakWindow-->
        <DropShadowEffect x:Key="AppDropShadowColor" 
              Color="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=DropShadowColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <!--this one does not leak-->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBackground"
              Color="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=DropShadowColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xml.cs** start MainWindow and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the property `DropShadowColor`.

```
 public partial class App : Application, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);        
            // start main window
            var mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();
        }

        private Color _dropShadowColor = Colors.Blue;    
        public Color DropShadowColor
        {
            get { return _dropShadowColor; }    
            set {
                _dropShadowColor = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DropShadowColor");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null) { handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }
        }
    }
```

**MainWindow.xml and MainWindow.xml.cs** has a button to create a `LeakWindow`, shown below.

```
var win = new LeakWindow {Owner = this};
win.Show();
```

There is also another button to do `GC.Collect()`;

**LeakWindow.xml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSimple.LeakWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Leak" Height="300" Width="300">
  <Grid>
    <!--leak-->
    <Border Width="200" Height="200" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Effect="{StaticResource AppDropShadowColor}"/>

    <!--no leak if comment out above and uncomment below-->
    <!--<Border  Width="200" Height="200" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="{StaticResource AppBackground}"/>-->
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**LeakWindow.xml.cs**

```
 public partial class LeakWindow : Window
    {
        public LeakWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    

        ~LeakWindow()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("LeakWindow finalized");
        }
    }
```

**Update**

- My search show this might be related to
  [DynamicResource\StaticResource cause memory leaks](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b97a5f83-5394-430e-9a78-9d3a957e3537/dynamicresourcestaticresource-cause-memory-leaks?forum=wpf). But that one is patched early in .NET 3.5([kb967328](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/967328)). Also tried the WalkDictionary method mentioned in that thread but no help.
- Change binding mode to `OneTime` does not help either.
- Switch to .NET 4.5 (also patched to date) and using `DynamicResource` does not help.

Further investigation shows the leak is caused by a `EventHandler` reference from `DropShadowEffect` to `Border.Effect`. Probably a change notification due to the binding in `DropShadowEffect`.
Still, what weird is **Why this only occurs on `Border.Effect` but not on `Border.Background`?**

**Workground**
Adding `x:Shared=false` to `<DropShadowEffect>` in app.xml can workaround this. I can now have application--wide defined resources but lose the memory efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is caused by the way `DropShadowEffect` is attached to the visual tree. Moving the `DropShadowEffect` into your control templates instead of having it as a resource might solve the leak, but then you would lose having that shared resource...

Comment: thanks Glen, `x:static` doesn't explain why `DropShadowEffect` leaks but `SolidColorBrush` does not.  I tried `Mode=OneTime` on `DropShadowEffect`, and surprisingly it still leaks. I will update these findings.

Comment: thank you Glen for the update. Yes you are correct (upvoted). Still what bothers me is why `Border.Background` does not leak while `Border.Effect` does?

Answer (score 0):

```
        <Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="WpfApplication.Window"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro" 
    ShowMaxRestoreButton="False" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowMinButton="False" 
        EnableDWMDropShadow="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Name="Window" 
Height="400" Width="567">
```

u can try to import mah apps it has drop shadow window
with a line EnableDWMDropShadow="True"

Comment: MahApps looks nice though I don't see it relates to my question.